# Grep for multiple pattern

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I have a file foo with content.

foo :

```
Transid: 1234 - first line
Transid:1234 - Second line.
In the Gap -Third line
1234 - fourth line
Transid: - fivth line.
```

1234 is the transaction id, which is used as a input to the below script.

```
itrans=1234
grep "Transid:*$i_trans" foo
```

Expected Output:

```
Transid: 1234 - first line
Transid:1234 - Second line.
```

Actual Output:

```
Transid:1234 - Second line.
```

Could you please help me to get the expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match also the space character .ie, add a space before `*`, so that it would match also the line which has space before `1234`.

```
grep "Transid: *$i_trans" foo
```

`<space>*` matches zero or more spaces. You may also use POSIX char class `[[:blank:]]` instead of space in the above regex.

Comment: If i have one or more spaces? also i am not sure about the number of spaces.

Comment: that's why i added ` *` in stead of ` +`